# Render field values in node template

Tags: 8

Hello I'm working on a module,
I currently have an array with Node objects (custom content types),
I am passing this array to a custom template (twig) but I can not render it with the values of its fields.

For example:

The dump object of the data that is coming to the template

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Node {#564 ▼
    +in_preview: null
    #values: array:24 [▶]
    #fields: array:2 [▶]
    #fieldDefinitions: array:32 [▶]
    #languages: null
    #langcodeKey: "langcode"
    #defaultLangcodeKey: "default_langcode"
    #activeLangcode: "x-default"
    #defaultLangcode: "es"
    #translations: array:1 [▶]
    #translationInitialize: false
    #newRevision: false
    #isDefaultRevision: "1"
    #entityKeys: array:4 [▶]
    #translatableEntityKeys: array:7 [▶]
    #validated: false
    #validationRequired: false
    #loadedRevisionId: "9"
    #revisionTranslationAffectedKey: "revision_translation_affected"
    #enforceRevisionTranslationAffected: []
    #entityTypeId: "node"
    #enforceIsNew: null
    #typedData: EntityAdapter {#1065 ▶}
    #cacheContexts: []
    #cacheTags: []
    #cacheMaxAge: -1
    #_serviceIds: []
  }
  1 => Node {#562 ▼
    +in_preview: null
    #values: array:24 [▶]
    #fields: array:2 [▶]
    #fieldDefinitions: array:32 [▶]
    #languages: null
    #langcodeKey: "langcode"
    #defaultLangcodeKey: "default_langcode"
    #activeLangcode: "x-default"
    #defaultLangcode: "es"
    #translations: array:1 [▶]
    #translationInitialize: false
    #newRevision: false
    #isDefaultRevision: "1"
    #entityKeys: array:4 [▶]
    #translatableEntityKeys: array:7 [▶]
    #validated: false
    #validationRequired: false
    #loadedRevisionId: "10"
    #revisionTranslationAffectedKey: "revision_translation_affected"
    #enforceRevisionTranslationAffected: []
    #entityTypeId: "node"
    #enforceIsNew: null
    #typedData: EntityAdapter {#1198 ▶}
    #cacheContexts: []
    #cacheTags: []
    #cacheMaxAge: -1
    #_serviceIds: []
  }
]
```

As you can see, the data is inside the key #values

```
#values: array:24 [▼
      "vid" => array:1 [▶]
      "langcode" => array:1 [▶]
      "revision_uid" => array:1 [▶]
      "revision_timestamp" => array:1 [▶]
      "revision_log" => array:1 [▶]
      "revision_default" => array:1 [▶]
      "nid" => array:1 [▶]
      "type" => array:1 [▶]
      "uuid" => array:1 [▶]
      "isDefaultRevision" => array:1 [▶]
      "status" => array:1 [▶]
      "title" => array:1 [▶]
      "uid" => array:1 [▶]
      "created" => array:1 [▶]
      "changed" => array:1 [▶]
      "promote" => array:1 [▶]
      "sticky" => array:1 [▶]
      "default_langcode" => array:1 [▶]
      "revision_translation_affected" => array:1 [▶]
      "field_custom_title" => array:1 [▶]

    ]
```

The twig template:

```
<ul>
    {% for node in nodos %}
        <li>{{ node.field_custom_title}}</li> #not work
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How do I get the values of the fields from twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought, it was simply using

```
{{ node.field_custom_title.value }}
```

Comment: Seems like it's time again to post the link to my blogpost: https://www.md-systems.ch/de/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig ;)